# Centering content vertically (and horizontally) in a div

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

First the example: http://jsfiddle.net/5S3mk/3/

I have a table whose columns need to be sortable so in the table header there should be links for sorting. The columns themselves are dynamic and their width is not known in advance.

In order to center the header content horizontally I used the recipe from [here](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/layouts/item/css-liquid-layout-22-fluid-fixed/).

Now I'm having trouble with adjusting the `spans` inside container `div` to center vertically. Does anyone have any idea how to do this (legacy browser are not an issue)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/paska/5S3mk/10/) you have one way of doing it. It uses a little jQuery script, but it is really simple.

Comment: thank you...i was hoping there was some simple CSS-only way, but I guess it's just easier using js